# How JVM maintains the relationship between class data and heap object?

Tags: java, linker, jvm

During the loading phase, the JVM creates the .class instance and other data structures specific to the classes.

This information is shared among multiple objects of same class.
I do not understand where does the JVM store the reference to the object.
It cannot save it in the method area as this is shared.

When Execution engine encounters a **new** the object is created and a reference is returned.
But where is this mapping between class data and object reference saved ?
Is it somewhere in the constant pool ? If so, is this pool a part of .class instance ?

Please help me here I went through JVM specification and Artima.

Comment: Why are you thinking so complicated? When you create on object, which implies reserving memory for the object, where would be the most natural place to store the type of the object?

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* headers that each Object in java has : called `mark` and `klass` pointers. Once all the metadata about the class is loaded, `klass` pointer points to that particular metadata.

Comment: I guess adding a link to some source would make that a really great answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an implementation detail.

The JVM is responsible for loading classes, and keeping track of them. It is also responsible for creating objects, and keeping track of the corresponding memory location.

But note: in the end, we are simply talking about various tables that the JVM needs to keep.

And how/where exactly such tables are stored is (most likely) not part of any specification. So that JVM implementations are free to do that in the ways it makes the most sense.

Comment: though correct (and vague?), this is an implementation detail, but it is a very known one.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that each object knows it's class (it has a reference to it's class), but classes don't know which instances exist.

To find the class of an object you can call it's `getClass()` method.

Comment: That doesnt address the question at all. The OP asks where in the JVM memory the "links" are kept. Not how to get to the Class object from within java itself.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica I wrote that "each object has a reference to it's class". To me this implies that is stored as part of the object itself.